# Unable to SSH into AWS EC2 instance with instance metadata turned off

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am not able to SSH into a EC2 instance if it is launched with the [instance metadata service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) is turned off.

```
ec2.runInstances({ ... MetadataOptions: {
  HttpEndpoint: 'disabled'..
})
```

This however is not an issue if I launch with the MetadataOptions enabled and disable it with a `modify-instance-metadata-options` call after the instance has finished starting up. Is this documented behaviour? I couldn't find it explicitly mentioned in the documentation anywhere.

Note - this is not a security group, Network ACL, etc issue.

Comment: Can you provide full example of the commands you are using?

Comment: That would be helpful. Also, why turn off metadata? The thing is, AWS instances are hard enough to SSH into as it is.

Comment: It is a normal `ec2.runInstance` via the ec2 js sdk. If I add `MetadataOptions: {HttpEndpoint: 'disabled'}` to the params of that function, i am no longer able to ssh in.
I have to turn off metadata for security reasons (our customers sort of can run commands on the servers we provision for them)

Comment: Have you examined the `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` file? It contains a log for the User Data script and might indicate that something went wrong during the startup process. What is the error you are receiving? Try `ssh -vvv` and edit your question to show the log messages produced.

Comment: I've had exact same issue when launching EC2 via web interface and disabling metadata option. It appears that it pulls SSH key from metadata endpoint while provisioning, hence disabling metadata breaks it. It is extremely confusing as there's never any warning that SSH pair wouldn't work.

Comment: I faced this same issue file a ticket here https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/29829

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this too. It seems that disabling IMDS breaks all of the following:

- SSH access is broken; the `authorized_keys` file for the default user (ie root or ubuntu) is not populated because the EC2 Key Pair is normally provided in instance metadata.
- Cloud-init/Cloud-config (aka "userdata") do not run. The user data is normally made available at `http://instance-data.:8773` but this is unavailable when IMDS is disabled.

Therefore, if your desire is to disable IMDS from the moment of launch, it seems the only viable workaround is to create your own AMI that has your own configuration (ie. SSH authorized_keys) backed into it. [Packer](https://www.packer.io) is commonly used for building AMIs in this way.

An alternate approach would be to give the EC2 instance profile permission to call [ModifyInstanceMetadataOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyInstanceMetadataOptions.html) conditionally scoped the instance can only affect itself, then call `aws ec2 modify-instance-metadata-options --http-endpoint disabled` at the end of the setup script. Once an instance locks itself out this way, it cannot unlock itself because it'll no longer have access to STS tokens via the IMDS endpoint.